# d3.js - rotated text label not align with points exactly

Tags: d3.js

Just try to plot a line chart with d3.js,the rotated x-axis label and annotation text value on each point looks like not match the point exactly!

How to adjust it to match the point?

```js
test()
function test() {
  var data = `tag,mean
boot_progress_start,10.882000000000001
boot_progress_preload_start,12.677
boot_progress_preload_end,15.962
boot_progress_system_run,16.441
boot_progress_pms_start,17.179
boot_progress_pms_system_scan_start,17.631
boot_progress_pms_scan_end,20.604
boot_progress_pms_ready,20.907
boot_progress_ams_ready,22.793000000000006
boot_progress_enable_screen,25.401
sf_stop_bootanim,25.427
`

  var dataset = d3.csvParse(data);
  dataset.forEach(d => {d.x = d.tag; d.y = +d.mean})

  var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}
  , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right
  , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(dataset.map(function(d) { return d.x; }));

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d){ return d.y; })])
  .range([height, 0]);

  var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(d.x); })
  .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", "3em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-30)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

  svg.append("path")
    .datum(dataset)
    .attr("class", "line") 
    .attr("d", line) 
    .attr('stroke','black')
    .attr('stroke-width',2)
    .attr('fill','none')
 
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(d.x) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) })
    .attr("r", 5)
  
   var anno = svg.selectAll(null)
   .data(dataset).enter()
   .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {return d.y.toFixed(1);})
  .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) - 15; })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr("font-size",10)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(45 " + xScale(d.x) + "," + yScale(d.y) + ")"
  });

  var lines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(dataset).enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("class", "stem-line")
  .attr("stroke", "green")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr("x1", function(d) { return xScale(d.x); } )
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return xScale(d.x); } )
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return yScale(0); } )
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return yScale(d.y); } );  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The position of your text is determined by at least three groups of parameters:

1. its coordinates, the `x` and `y` attributes
2. its `text-anchor` to position it at the left/center/right of your coordinates
3. its baseline, see the [`alignement-baseline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline) and [`dominant-baseline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline) reference in the Mozilla documentation.

That being said, you are positioning your text with `.attr("x",9)`, you are rotating it by -30 degrees with `.attr("transform", "rotate(-30)")` and you are anchoring it to the end with `.style("text-anchor", "end")`. I would not rotate it and I would anchor it it to the middle:

```
test()
function test() {
  var data = `tag,mean
boot_progress_start,10.882000000000001
boot_progress_preload_start,12.677
boot_progress_preload_end,15.962
boot_progress_system_run,16.441
boot_progress_pms_start,17.179
boot_progress_pms_system_scan_start,17.631
boot_progress_pms_scan_end,20.604
boot_progress_pms_ready,20.907
boot_progress_ams_ready,22.793000000000006
boot_progress_enable_screen,25.401
sf_stop_bootanim,25.427
`

  var dataset = d3.csvParse(data);
  dataset.forEach(d => {d.x = d.tag; d.y = +d.mean})

  var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}
  , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right
  , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(dataset.map(function(d) { return d.x; }));

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d){ return d.y; })])
  .range([height, 0]);

  var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(d.x); })
  .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", "3em")
    // changing the rotation to 0 or remove it
    .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
    // anchoring the text at the center
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

  svg.append("path")
    .datum(dataset)
    .attr("class", "line") 
    .attr("d", line) 
    .attr('stroke','black')
    .attr('stroke-width',2)
    .attr('fill','none')
 
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(d.x) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) })
    .attr("r", 5)
  
   var anno = svg.selectAll(null)
   .data(dataset).enter()
   .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {return d.y.toFixed(1);})
  .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) - 15; })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr("font-size",10)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(45 " + xScale(d.x) + "," + yScale(d.y) + ")"
  });

  var lines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(dataset).enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("class", "stem-line")
  .attr("stroke", "green")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr("x1", function(d) { return xScale(d.x); } )
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return xScale(d.x); } )
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return yScale(0); } )
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return yScale(d.y); } );  
}
```

#### An additional note on the rotation

As you may know, because you are doing it for the **anno**, you can chose a point to rotate your object from. If you want it to rotate on itself, you will have to specify the object's own coordinates:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(45 " + xScale(d.x) + " " + yScale(d.y) + ")"
  });
```

Comment: the better way to answer this question is to copy the snippet to your answer and demonstrate how it solves the problem visually

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm pretty new to it! Just updated the answer, hope it can help